# How to print in python the values which match in a single line with comma separated

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to get the output of all the "hostname matches in single line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

for Y in open("/tmp/inventory_file"):
    if 'hostX' in Y:
           value = Y.split('|')[1]
           print(value,sep=',')
```

I have multiple matches printing in rows. How can i print them in a single line with comma separated?

Comment: Please include a sample of your data and the expected output.

Comment: You really should not be learning Python 2 in 2018. The supported and recommended version of the language is Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you are readling contains special charactors  may be "\r\n" charactors i.e carriage return and new line charactor.

you can use strip() method before splitting the line to remove "\r\n" at the end. Also you need to use end="" argument in print method.

use below example:

```
from __future__ import print_function

for Y in open("/tmp/inventory_file"):
    if 'hostX' in Y:
       value = Y.strip().split('|')[1]
       print(value,end=', ')
```

**Below is edited section for your comment::**

As you are printing output in a loop, so it is not a good idea to store this to a variable rather you can use a list to store values and also if needed you can make a single string variable from that list. see my below examples

```
from __future__ import print_function
result = []
for Y in open("/tmp/inventory_file"):
    if 'hostX' in Y:
        result.append(Y.strip().split('|')[1])

print(result)   #printing output as list
s = ", ".join(result)  #creating output as single string variable
print(s)   #printing output as string variable
```

Comment: print(alias,end=', ') works fine, it gives me the output in single line but is it possibile to store the output in a variable ?

Comment: As you are printing output in a loop, so it is not a good idea to store this to a variable rather you can use a list to store values and also if needed you can make a single string variable from that string. see my below examples:

Comment: @user3089693 Please upvote my answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It’s pretty easy! `value = Y.split('|')[1]` will get you a list of matches, and then pick the 2nd one.

What we want is the list, so remove the `[1]`.

Now, the print function:

> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

The `*` before *objects*, means you can put as many arguments as you want, like

```
print('hello', 'pal', sep=' ')
```

But if you want to transform a list to those multiple arguments, you have to put an `*` before.

So in the end, it gives us

```
value = Y.split('|')
print(*value,sep=',')
```

Comment: Input file has 2 columns and i am matching the hostX in column1 and getting column2.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `sep=` is that it specifies what to put between two values.

```
>>> print('moo', 'bar', sep=',')
moo,bar
```

To specify to use a different line terminator, you want `end=','` instead.  But really, the proper way to collect and print these values is probably just to collect them into a list, and print the list when you are done.

```
values = []
for Y in open("/tmp/inventory_file"):
    if 'hostX' in Y:
           values.append(Y.split('|')[1])
print(','.join(values))
```